# errors with gradle in android studio

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, google-glass, android-studio-2.1

I am trying to build the project and run it in my google glass but when ever i am trying to build it is showing that

Error:(20, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'runProguard()'
Possible causes:

The project 'gdk-stopwatch-sample' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
Gradle settings

The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
Apply Gradle plugin

but i have installed the latest gradle plugin i.e 2.13, changed the classpath in build.gradle to 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3', gradle-wrapper properties to (distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.13-all.zip), deleted the .gradle file in Users but it keeps on appearing again and again, and also in settings I marked as offline work, service directory path keeps on appearing though

Updated Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application>
    <uses-library android:name="android.test.runner" />
</application>

<instrumentation android:name="android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
                 android:targetPackage="com.google.android.glass.sample.stopwatch"
                 android:handleProfiling="false"
                 android:functionalTest="false"
                 android:label="Tests for com.google.android.glass.sample.stopwatch"/>
```

Comment: Post your gradle  file

Comment: i have uploaded build.gradle image

Comment: Can you post whole code(gradle)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It happens because the gradle plugin for Android **2.1.3 doesn't exist**.
Don't confuse the gradle version with the gradle plugin.

Use

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
    }
}
```

About the `runProguard` change your script with:

```
release {
    minifyEnabled true 
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `minifyEnabled()` instead of `runProguard()`

So the code will look like

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
```

Comment: In the gradle wrapper properties should i use 2.10 or 2.13 because now the build is successful but while trying to run in glass it says default activity not found

Comment: Try 2.1.0 as @Gabriele says 2.1.3 doesn't exist

Comment: Build is successfull but while running that example it says - 
Could not identify launch activity: Default Activity not found
Error while Launching activity. So i tried to run another sample by using the same settings and changing the runproguard to minifyEnabled but it says "Error:The 'java' plugin has been applied, but it is not compatible with the Android plugins."

Comment: @komy029 File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart. Then also sync it

Comment: yeah done that but still the same results first sample shows: Could not identify launch activity ; second one =Error:The 'java' plugin has been applied, but it is not compatible with the Android plugins.

Comment: Remove the `apply plugin: ' java ' `

Comment: Thank you for the help, now the build is successful in both the examples but it is not possible to run them they both keep on saying "Could not identify launch activity: Default Activity not found
Error while Launching activity"

Comment: @komy029 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33855518/could-not-identify-launch-activity-default-activity-not-found

Answer (score 0):

Issue Error with gradle plugin not getting updated resolved - If you are getting this error you should update the plugin version to 2.1.2 or 2.3.1 (Be careful it is 2.1.2 and not not 2.12). Here is the sample project level build.gradle that resolved my error-

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1'
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```