# Android Studio gradle 2.1.3 issue

Tags: android, android-studio, libgdx, android-gradle-plugin

**Gradle Issue in Android Studio 2.1.3**

I got those errors when i run the  **Desktop** application that i've created based on the [Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rzBVTPaUUDg).

where i can find that Gradle 2.1.3?  Please help me. Im using **Libgdx** framework. Thank you in advance.

[image]

> Error:Gradle: A problem occurred configuring root project 'Flapp Bird'.
>   Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
>   Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3.
>        Searched in the following locations:
>            file:/C:/Users/Unknown/.m2/repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.1.3/gradle-2.1.3.pom
>            file:/C:/Users/Unknown/.m2/repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.1.3/gradle-2.1.3.jar
>
> https:://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.1.3/gradle-2.1.3.
>   https:://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.1.3/gradle-2.1.3.jar
>            https:://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.1.3/gradle-2.1.3.pom
>            https:://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.1.3/gradle-2.1.3.jar
>
> Required by:
>            :Flapp Bird:unspecified

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The Gradle version 2.1.3 exists, but is not in the Maven central, as said [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=220117).

To fix the issue, just add **jcenter()** after **mavenCentral()** in your build script.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'
    }
}
```

Comment: I had the exact same problem and this solved it! Thanks!

Comment: **UPDATE:**
Thank you very much sir **manelizzard**
100% works

Answer (score 4):

No, Ivan is right. The latest version of Android Studio insists on upgrading to Android Plugin for Gradle, Revision 2.1.3 (August 2016), Gradle 2.14.1 or higher and Build Tools 23.0.2 or higher.
[image: Studio Message]
But the moment it does that, it breaks compilation with that error:

```
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'. Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3. Searched in the following locations:
```

Comment: yes. i updated my android studio yesterday. I think that's why i got this errors .

Answer (score 1):

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.7.3'
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'
   }
}
```

For me adding this: `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.7.3'` did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, the latest version of Gradle is 2.1.2. You might be confusing the gradle version with the gradle plugin. A similar question to yours was also answered over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37277805/errors-with-gradle-in-android-studio) Just change `'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'` to `2.1.2`and you should be set.

Comment: i'll already try to set the 2.1.3 to 2.1.2 and 2.1.0 but it gives me another error