# why doesn't task wrapper function work

Tags: android, gradle, ionic-framework, build.gradle

There are many good suggestions to how to fix gradle versions, but some of them are outdated or I just couldn't find the paths that were suggested. one solution did work for me is **project>project structure>project>gradle version**.

Here I can change it to the supported version, and successfully builds the project.

A small error in the the javascript code, so a change is made to it. `Ionic build android`, now something wrong occurrs here. `Minimum supprted Gradle version is 2.14.1. Current version is 2.13.`.

But in the **project/platforms/android/build.gradle**

`task wrapper(type: Wrapper){
   gradleVersion = '2.14.1'
}`

and from this [link](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html), it suggests that this is the way set your gradle wrapper.

So I am expecting in **project/platforms/android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties** to have `distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip`, instead this is what it has `distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.13-all.zip`.

Can't make direct change to this file **project/platforms/android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties**, because after each build it will revert back to `gradle-2.13-all.zip`.

What is going on here? can't find anything that explain why it keeps on changing the `distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.13-all.zip`. Would anyone be kindly explain this please? Maybe something very stupid that I have missed. Thank you.

**Links that I have looked at**

["Gradle Version 2.10 is required." Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34814368/gradle-version-2-10-is-required-error)

[How to update gradle in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17727645/how-to-update-gradle-in-android-studio)

[ionic build android error when download gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29874564/ionic-build-android-error-when-download-gradle)

**gradle code**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }

    // Switch the Android Gradle plugin version requirement depending on the
    // installed version of Gradle. This dependency is documented at
    // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/version-compatibility
    // and https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-8143
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.1'
    }
}

// Allow plugins to declare Maven dependencies via build-extras.gradle.
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral();
        jcenter();
    }
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.14.1'
}

// Configuration properties. Set these via environment variables, build-extras.gradle, or gradle.properties.
// Refer to: http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/tutorial_this_and_that.html
ext {
    apply from: 'CordovaLib/cordova.gradle'
    // The value for android.compileSdkVersion.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvCompileSdkVersion')) {
        cdvCompileSdkVersion = null;
    }
    // The value for android.buildToolsVersion.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvBuildToolsVersion')) {
        cdvBuildToolsVersion = null;
    }
    // Sets the versionCode to the given value.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvVersionCode')) {
        cdvVersionCode = null
    }
    // Sets the minSdkVersion to the given value.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvMinSdkVersion')) {
        cdvMinSdkVersion = null
    }
    // Whether to build architecture-specific APKs.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvBuildMultipleApks')) {
        cdvBuildMultipleApks = null
    }
    // .properties files to use for release signing.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile')) {
        cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile = null
    }
    // .properties files to use for debug signing.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile')) {
        cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile = null
    }
    // Set by build.js script.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvBuildArch')) {
        cdvBuildArch = null
    }

    // Plugin gradle extensions can append to this to have code run at the end.
    cdvPluginPostBuildExtras = []
}

// PLUGIN GRADLE EXTENSIONS START
apply from: "cordova-plugin-badge/simplelogin777664-badge.gradle"
// PLUGIN GRADLE EXTENSIONS END

def hasBuildExtras = file('build-extras.gradle').exists()
if (hasBuildExtras) {
    apply from: 'build-extras.gradle'
}

// Set property defaults after extension .gradle files.
if (ext.cdvCompileSdkVersion == null) {
    ext.cdvCompileSdkVersion = privateHelpers.getProjectTarget()
}
if (ext.cdvBuildToolsVersion == null) {
    ext.cdvBuildToolsVersion = privateHelpers.findLatestInstalledBuildTools()
}
if (ext.cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile == null && file('debug-signing.properties').exists()) {
    ext.cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile = 'debug-signing.properties'
}
if (ext.cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile == null && file('release-signing.properties').exists()) {
    ext.cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile = 'release-signing.properties'
}

// Cast to appropriate types.
ext.cdvBuildMultipleApks = cdvBuildMultipleApks == null ? false : cdvBuildMultipleApks.toBoolean();
ext.cdvMinSdkVersion = cdvMinSdkVersion == null ? null : Integer.parseInt('' + cdvMinSdkVersion)
ext.cdvVersionCode = cdvVersionCode == null ? null : Integer.parseInt('' + cdvVersionCode)

def computeBuildTargetName(debugBuild) {
    def ret = 'assemble'
    if (cdvBuildMultipleApks && cdvBuildArch) {
        def arch = cdvBuildArch == 'arm' ? 'armv7' : cdvBuildArch
        ret += '' + arch.toUpperCase().charAt(0) + arch.substring(1);
    }
    return ret + (debugBuild ? 'Debug' : 'Release')
}

// Make cdvBuild a task that depends on the debug/arch-sepecific task.
task cdvBuildDebug
cdvBuildDebug.dependsOn {
    return computeBuildTargetName(true)
}

task cdvBuildRelease
cdvBuildRelease.dependsOn {
    return computeBuildTargetName(false)
}

task cdvPrintProps << {
    println('cdvCompileSdkVersion=' + cdvCompileSdkVersion)
    println('cdvBuildToolsVersion=' + cdvBuildToolsVersion)
    println('cdvVersionCode=' + cdvVersionCode)
    println('cdvMinSdkVersion=' + cdvMinSdkVersion)
    println('cdvBuildMultipleApks=' + cdvBuildMultipleApks)
    println('cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile=' + cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile)
    println('cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile=' + cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile)
    println('cdvBuildArch=' + cdvBuildArch)
    println('computedVersionCode=' + android.defaultConfig.versionCode)
    android.productFlavors.each { flavor ->
        println('computed' + flavor.name.capitalize() + 'VersionCode=' + flavor.versionCode)
    }
}

android {
  sourceSets {
    main {
      manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
      java.srcDirs = ['src']
      resources.srcDirs = ['src']
      aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
      renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
      res.srcDirs = ['res']
      assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
      jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
    }
  }
  defaultConfig {
    if (cdvMinSdkVersion != null) {
      minSdkVersion cdvMinSdkVersion
    }
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
  }
  lintOptions {
    abortOnError false;
  }
  compileSdkVersion 23
  buildToolsVersion '21.1.2'
  if (Boolean.valueOf(cdvBuildMultipleApks)) {
    productFlavors {
      armv7 {
        versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode * 10 + 2
        ndk {
          abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", ""
        }
      }
      x86 {
        versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode * 10 + 4
        ndk {
          abiFilters "x86", ""
        }
      }
      all {
        ndk {
          abiFilters "all", ""
        }
      }
    }
  }
  /*

  ELSE NOTHING! DON'T MESS WITH THE VERSION CODE IF YOU DON'T HAVE TO!

  else if (!cdvVersionCode) {
    def minSdkVersion = cdvMinSdkVersion ?: privateHelpers.extractIntFromManifest("minSdkVersion")
    // Vary versionCode by the two most common API levels:
    // 14 is ICS, which is the lowest API level for many apps.
    // 20 is Lollipop, which is the lowest API level for the updatable system webview.
    if (minSdkVersion >= 20) {
      defaultConfig.versionCode += 9
    } else if (minSdkVersion >= 14) {
      defaultConfig.versionCode += 8
    }
  }
  */
  compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
  }
  if (cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile) {
    signingConfigs {
      release {
        // These must be set or Gradle will complain (even if they are overridden).
        keyAlias = ""
        keyPassword = "__unset"
        // And these must be set to non-empty in order to have the signing step added to the task graph.
        storeFile = null
        storePassword = "__unset"
      }
    }
    buildTypes {
      release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
      }
    }
    addSigningProps(cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile, signingConfigs.release)
  }
  if (cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile) {
    addSigningProps(cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile, signingConfigs.debug)
  }
  productFlavors {
  }
}

dependencies {
  compile fileTree(include: '*.jar', dir: 'libs')
  // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES START
    debugCompile project(path: "CordovaLib", configuration: "debug")
    releaseCompile project(path: "CordovaLib", configuration: "release")
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:+"
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES END
}

def promptForReleaseKeyPassword() {
    if (!cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile) {
        return;
    }
    if ('__unset'.equals(android.signingConfigs.release.storePassword)) {
        android.signingConfigs.release.storePassword = privateHelpers.promptForPassword('Enter key store password: ')
    }
    if ('__unset'.equals(android.signingConfigs.release.keyPassword)) {
        android.signingConfigs.release.keyPassword = privateHelpers.promptForPassword('Enter key password: ');
    }
}

gradle.taskGraph.whenReady { taskGraph ->
    taskGraph.getAllTasks().each() { task ->
        if (task.name == 'validateReleaseSigning') {
            promptForReleaseKeyPassword()
        }
    }
}

def addSigningProps(propsFilePath, signingConfig) {
    def propsFile = file(propsFilePath)
    def props = new Properties()
    propsFile.withReader { reader ->
        props.load(reader)
    }

    def storeFile = new File(props.get('key.store') ?: privateHelpers.ensureValueExists(propsFilePath, props, 'storeFile'))
    if (!storeFile.isAbsolute()) {
        storeFile = RelativePath.parse(true, storeFile.toString()).getFile(propsFile.getParentFile())
    }
    if (!storeFile.exists()) {
        throw new FileNotFoundException('Keystore file does not exist: ' + storeFile.getAbsolutePath())
    }
    signingConfig.keyAlias = props.get('key.alias') ?: privateHelpers.ensureValueExists(propsFilePath, props, 'keyAlias')
    signingConfig.keyPassword = props.get('keyPassword', props.get('key.alias.password', signingConfig.keyPassword))
    signingConfig.storeFile = storeFile
    signingConfig.storePassword = props.get('storePassword', props.get('key.store.password', signingConfig.storePassword))
    def storeType = props.get('storeType', props.get('key.store.type', ''))
    if (!storeType) {
        def filename = storeFile.getName().toLowerCase();
        if (filename.endsWith('.p12') || filename.endsWith('.pfx')) {
            storeType = 'pkcs12'
        } else {
            storeType = signingConfig.storeType // "jks"
        }
    }
    signingConfig.storeType = storeType
}

for (def func : cdvPluginPostBuildExtras) {
    func()
}

// This can be defined within build-extras.gradle as:
//     ext.postBuildExtras = { ... code here ... }
if (hasProperty('postBuildExtras')) {
    postBuildExtras()
}
```

**Update**

'gradlew wrapper throws error, because certain wrapper doesn't exist under maven and the sub `build.gradle` uses it to download `2.14.1.prom` and `2.14.1.jar`. [This link will explain it.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39000831/android-studio-graddle-2-1-3-issue)

**Found problem**

The problem why it keeps on changing back to `2.13-all.zip` is because of this line, `var distributionUrl = process.env['CORDOVA_ANDROID_GRADLE_DISTRIBUTION_URL'] || 'http\\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.13-all.zip';` in the `[project name]/platforms/android/cordova/lib/builders/GradleBuilder.js` instead of `~/android/lib/GradleBuilder.js`. (Line 164)

Comment: Doesn't affect anything, but note that you can just do this terser syntax: `wrapper {
       gradleVersion = '2.14.1'
    }`

Comment: Thanks @weston, but somehow it still gives me the same error

Comment: Yeah, I did say "Doesn't affect anything" It wasn't meant to be a fix, just a tip.

Comment: You don't have any `wrapper` tasks defined in the subprojects build.gradle files do you?

Comment: two `build.gradle` files, but only one has `wrapper` task and it is the one I mentioned above.

Comment: Out of ideas, perhaps post whole gradle file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem why it keeps on changing back to 2.13-all.zip is because of this line, `var distributionUrl = process.env['CORDOVA_ANDROID_GRADLE_DISTRIBUTION_URL'] || 'http\\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.13-all.zip';` in the `[project name]/platforms/android/cordova/lib/builders/GradleBuilder.js` instead of `~/android/lib/GradleBuilder.js`. (Line 164)

Answer (score 51):

**HERE IS A FIX :: Add this in Gradle File**

```
task wrapper(type: Wrapper){
   gradleVersion = '7.2'
}
```

Answer (score 14):

This fixed it for me :

```
task wrapper(type: Wrapper){
     gradleVersion = '4.1.2'
}
```

Add this task to **build.gradle** file

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure why gradle would be updating the `gradle-wrapper.properties` file like that. But the way the `wrapper` task works means you need to invoke it to make a change, so try the following commands.

In `project/platforms/android/`:

- `./gradlew wrapper` - This updates the wrapper to the specified version
- `./gradlew --version` Since gradlew uses the wrapper it will download the newer version if its not already cached on your machine somewhere. At the top it SHOULD say `2.14.1` after doing this

Comment: Hi @kiskae, just want to be sure if I understand your suggestions correctly. I used command prompt, in the `project/platforms/android/` and used this commands. I have `Gradle 2.13` as a return if i used `gradlew --version` and failed with minimum version error if used `gradlew`. I can't use the `./` in the command prompt.

Comment: Why can't you use `./gradlew`? What happens if you do?

Comment: sorry, it doesn't work. this is the message i get if I try to use it  `'.' is not recognised as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file`.

Comment: odd, what operating system is this on? and what terminal? `.` is pretty standard for current directory

Comment: Oh, yeah I think windows you must leave it off, but it does the same. Only other thing I would try is `gradle wrapper` Note, no `w`. Requires gradle to be installed. Then do `gradlew -v`

Comment: `'gradle' is not recognised as an internal or external command`, but `'gradlew' works. Accidentally, i ran `gradlew`. it failed because `problem occurred configuring root project 'android' and ':CordvoaLib'. it could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':CordovaLib:classpath'. Could not find 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.1'. Searched in the following locations: https:/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.1/gradle-2.2.1.pom and https:/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.1/gradle-2.2.1.jar. Required by 'android:Cordovalib:unspecified'`

Comment: after running `gradlew -v`, gradle version 1.14.1 but reverted back to 1.13 the moment I try to run ionic build android.

Comment: One thing you could try is to upgrade with `gradlew wrapper` and then making the gradle-wrapper.properties file read only. Then see if some part of your toolchain complains

Answer (score 2):

It seems that for my (downloaded) project, gradle-wrapper.properties was missing. I simply copied it over from another project and placed it in at top level where settings.gradle and other files are present.
After that I used the Android Studio --> File --> Settings --> Build, Execution, Deployment --> Build Tools --> Gradle and specified the path to the gradle-wrapper.properties file.

Post that the project sync'd successfully and an update gradle-wrapper.properties file was generated.

The gradle-wrapper.properties used by me.

```
#Tue Nov 17 19:42:26 IST 2020
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0.2-all.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Eclipse, just change the version (example gradleVersion = '4.8') and run the 'wrapper' task under 'build-setup' (Gradle Tasks View) and console output would be

```
Working Directory: C:\aa\gradle-jar
Gradle User Home: C:\Users\aa\.gradle
Gradle Distribution: Gradle wrapper from target build
Gradle Version: 4.8
Java Home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91
```