# Error: Could not identify launch activity: Default activity not found

Tags: java, android, android-studio, java-8

I have had this problem for a while and I thought I would just repost this because there isn't really a solution for this problem around. I just installed android studio 2.1.3 and I have been having this problem:

Could not identify launch activity: Default Activity not found
Error while Launching activity

...
I have this problem with existing projects BUT I also have this problem when I make a new project ?? What am I doing wrong ? And I've tried all suggested solutions and nothing seems to be working. Any idea's ? Thanks !

Little sidenote, all these projects worked perfectly so I don't think this is a namespace or any other typo problem. And the fact that new projects don't even launch makes it even weirder...

Comment: This happens even though you declare launch activity in the manifest?

Comment: I have this inside my AndroidManifest.xml file:
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
@Shaishav

Comment: Yeah...thats weird. Try `File > Invalidate Caches / Restart`

Comment: @Shaishav Tried that multiple times already :/

Comment: I'm out of ideas. If you can, try installing a previous version of AS side by side to this and check there.

Comment: @Shaishav I thought it would come to that :/ ... Thanks for the idea's though! Imma keep trying some things and then just reinstall if neccassary

Comment: Need to refresh the IDE's cache Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15825081/error-default-activity-not-found

Comment: @DarthSwedo goto edit app configuration(at the right side of run button in menu bar). In there set the default activity to the class you want to. I think that might be the issue.

Comment: Halumz Shaishav already told me that but that doesn't help a thing :(
@code-crusher If I go to run/debug configurations I don't even see an activity part

Comment: Are there any activities that are listed in the manifest but don't actually exist? I've seen that error because of this before.

Comment: @DarthSwedo edit this. http://imgur.com/a/7Q49M. Or add a specific one as you like.

Comment: edit post and add your manifest content

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not identify launch Activity: Default Activity not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33855518/could-not-identify-launch-activity-default-activity-not-found)

Comment: Give Mainfest file and I would tell you the solution