# I often found this specific error: "Could not identify launch activity: Default Activity not found Error while Launching activity"

Tags: android

This is my adb shell commands to install application, each time when i install app, it show default activity not found.

```
$ adb shell pm install -t -r "/data/local/tmp/it.dabbl"
    Success
    APK installed in 9 s 725 ms
    Could not identify launch activity: Default Activity not found
    Error while Launching activity
```

Comment: Have you declared the launch activity in AndroidManifest?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: Default Activity Not Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15825081/error-default-activity-not-found)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not identify launch Activity: Default Activity not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33855518/could-not-identify-launch-activity-default-activity-not-found)

Comment: @B001ᛦ Yes i have declared.

Comment: @KaranHarshWardhan,Yes this question is duplicate but not found solution yet.

Comment: _Yes i have declared_ Does it look similar to @Ashish answer?

Comment: @SaadBilal post your manifest before people put more flags

Comment: @SaadBilal if you don't post more details, it's likely your question will be closed. have you tried everything in the stack link i posted? post more details

Comment: please see my answer guys, i have solved issue. Explanation in answer

Answer (score 0):

you have to define your launcher activity in manifest.

```
  <activity
    android:name=".MainActivity" //Whatever Activity you want to launch first>
      <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
  </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

So after searching on internet over an hour, i have check from project structure that i have not set the default config settings. To resolve this issue you have to open project structure and then add default config and then synced with gradle will solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and solved it by manually setting the launch activity. From the menu select "Run -> Edit Configurations...", and then under "Launch Options" select "Launch: Specified Activity" and "Activity: your.launch.activity" where "your.launch.activity" is the activity you want to launch.