# Flutter Android tap on notification does not open app

Tags: android, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I am using `firebase_cloud_messaging` in my Flutter app and I can receive notifications just fine, but when tapping them, nothing happens. While testing, the app was always in the background. I read that by default, it should open the app. What am I missing here?

Do I have to specify something so the app opens? It works fine on iOS.

Let me know if you need any more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing the following `intent-filter`. Adding this makes the notifications open the app.

See  [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33855565/11968226) for more info.

```
  <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
```